# Multi-thread debugging with VisualStudio and WebBrowser Windows.Forms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, visual-studio

We're creating a few threads in a Windows.Forms solution.

We've also got a BrowserControl (yup, it's OAUTH) and of course I'm finding issues with debugging -

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'xxForm' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on

And yet I am calling 'correctly'

> xxForm.Show()

by ensuring it's wrapped in an invoke call

> .Invoke(new MethodInvoker())

and still I get the thread issue. I can do everything else (Focus, BringToFront) it's the Show that errors.

Moreover, the GUI never gets the browser response and shows. In the VS debugger I get the above threading erropr (apartment state of background thread == MTA). When run as an EXE the same code has a threading aparement of STA and the GUI will never show when debugging, but if I run the EXE directly, there's no threading issue, the browser control just never responds to input.

Spo the questions are:

- Why the different behjaviour in VS / EXE?
- How do I debug in VS?
- Does the BrowserControl play ok with multiple threads?

**Update**

YES I KNOW there's no code - it's too long. I'll see what I can do.

Also please read the question before posting an answer. I am invoking the background thread on the UI thread. That's not the issue. This has NO EFFECT on the result. I'll down vote answers that recommend that.

Also some hope - I've searched for many hours. It's linked the the message pump. Unless the message pump is running the DocumentCompleted event isn't received.

**Update 2**
Best I manage is pseudo code:

Program:

```
 startWorkQueue
 LoadForm (don't show)
```

Thread1:

```
 addToQueue
```

Thread2:

```
 readFromQueue
 ShowForm (on occasion)
```

Now the ShowForm method is on a Windows.Form control.
Within this any call is made via an Invoke, so that despite the 2nd thread making the call the ShowForm, the actual .Show() etc etc calls are on the UI thread.

So what am I missing? I just don't understand why there's a cross thread exception....

Comment: Please show us your code and stack trace.

Comment: The reason it only breaks when debugging and not in release builds is that the threaded access to controls is stricter when debugging.  You're introducing a race condition by accessing the control from another thread and it's warning you of that.  I will *sometimes* break in the release build, but you won't know when, and the symptoms can very greatly, making it a debugging nightmare, which is why in debug builds it *always* breaks when you access a control from the wrong thread, and it does so right away.

Comment: Yeah but I'm calling the Control.Invoke() ... so I'm not sure *Why* it's not being run on the right thread...

Comment: Hi servy - thanks for that, but I am making all the calls via Invoke calls. I suspect it's because the form holds a WebBrowser ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found out what was going on and I'll post here for reference.
I hope it helps someone in the future.

We had some different constraint to the vanilla Forms applications - our Forms were created on the Main thread but had Show() called on a different thread. We also don't have a starting UI - we sit in the background and sometimes react to events with UI prompts.

As such a number of issues hit us. Rather than list them all I'll detail our takeaways:

**Application.Run**

- If decide NOT to Show a Form at the start of your application… then you'll need to consider threads carefully (see Form.Show notes)

**Form.Show**

- This does all resource allocation etc, NOT the Load/ctor
- Performs handle creation / resource allocation

**Handle creation**

- Hwnd
- If we attempt to access certain Form properties before it has Show(n) then you'll need to create a handle manually (or an Exception is created)

  • As easy as `if (!IsHandleCreated)            {                CreateHandle();            }`

**HOWEVER**

- This create the control/form
- Therefore the control/form is created on the Thread that calls the Handle create
- This must be the same UI thread (STA) as the Main function

  • Otherwise much weirdness occurs

**SO**

- You aren't restricted by what to do with Application.Run
- You can access properties in .Show (but you may need to create a handle first)
- You can call Show from a different thread, but ensure the handle is ONLY created on the main thread

I hope it helps, I can provide more details on our specific problems if need be.

Various aids that helped included displaying ManagedThread AND ProcessId in the log and scouring MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code has not been pasted, I would like to remind you that in WinForms, the UI elements should be accessed only on the UI thread. Any other thread apart from UI thread should not be updating the UI elements directly.